# Why am I getting 'permission denied' error in Jenkins but not when bash-ing into DIND image?

Tags: docker, jenkins

Jenkins and docker

Hello, I have installed jenkins on my main computer using docker desktop with the recommended current jenkins image. On that same windows computer I created an ubuntu VM with vmware. On the ubuntu VM I installed the docker engine. I also installed sysbox-runc runtime to use with dind. In jenkins I added the ubuntu vm has a permanent agent and everything is working except the docker client commands.

My JenkinsFile look like this

```
pipeline {
agent { docker {
    image 'custom dind image with java and maven'
    registryCredentialsId 'credential'
    args '-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
 } }
stages {
    codecheckout
    ...
    stage('compile') {
        steps {
            sh 'mvn compile'
        }
    }

    stage('test') {
        steps {
            sh 'mvn test'
        }
    }

    stage('build jar') {
        steps {
            sh 'mvn clean compile assembly:single'
        }
    }

    stage('docker build') {
        steps {
            sh 'docker build -t img/img .'
        }
    }
}
```

}

It all work except the last one sh 'docker build -t img/img .'
It says ERROR: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

My jenkins start the agent on ubuntu via the launch method "Launch agents via SSH".

I added the ssh user that jenkins is using to start the agent in the docker group. It still does the error. So far the only way it work is if I cheat and put 777 perm on docker.sock.

The wierd thing is when using the ubuntu terminal, I run a dind image and go on it, I don't have any error and all docker commands work. It is only when jenkins does it with the docker agent that it has some kind of permission issues.

I've spend more so much time on this, does someone have ideas?

Comment: What is the point of using dind image if you are mouting docker.sock from host??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Jenkins passes `-u jenkins` or the user id you are running your jenkins worker with to the docker container, so you are running as Jenkins user with Jenkins user permissions inside the docker container. However (you are completely ignoring your "dind" image and) you are mounting docker from host, and Jenkins user inside the container is most probably unknown user without any groups, so it has no permission to access the docker.sock.

Comment: it pass this : docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 not -u jenkins.

on ubuntu the 1000 user correspond to the ssh user jenkins is using. It is unknown on the image.

I don't understand what you mean by "you are completely ignoring your "dind" image"

Comment: `it pass this` It passes the uid the jenkins worker is running with. Either way, the resulting uid and groups do not have access to docker.sock. `I don't understand what you mean by` DIND image starts it's own docker inside the docker container. By mounting docker.sock _from host_, you are prohibiting docker-in-docker to start, because docker.sock already exists from host, so dockerd inside docker can't start.

Comment: The reason I added the volume is because without it. It says ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Instead of a permission issue.
I'm using docker:dind atm for testing only the part that does'nt work to be sure that its not my custom image that brake something.

Comment: Dind image runs dockerd process as entrypoint. When running in Jenkins, it runs the Jenkins script, not dockerd. So dockerd is not running at all. You might as well just use any image with docker command line inside, as you are not using dind. Sadly, interaction of Jenkins with docker is a very confusing journey. Consider just `sh 'docker run  the_stuff_you_want_to_do'` instead or writing a Dockerfile, or using gitlab or github or bitbucket.